# Is it possible to build social networking website using WordPress?

Tags: users, performance

Can one WordPress install handle at least 100,000 user profile pages (5m visitors a month), 20-100 pictures per profile, taging, facebook-like wall, private messaging system etc.?

What's the limit with WordPress? When thigs will get really slow?

The biggest sites I've seen so far are Envato's marketplaces like ThemeForest but content there is added by editors, mostly.

Do you have any examples of such sites?

Comment: It depends in your server because wordpress use your database and your hosting so it depends in your server and if you're using wordpress.com and upgrading your limitations then it also supports in wordpress there are VIP service also vip.wordpress.com

Answer (score 1):

WordPress can handle large databases and high traffic quite well. I think one good example of this was seeing some WordPress sites holdup to high traffic when the recent iPhone announcement happened.

This really comes down to how well you code your theme/plugins, how you manage caching and your server configuration. WordPress will not be a bottleneck for you so long as you don't screw it up with bad code.

For a social plugin, check you BuddyPress, which is the de facto standard for such sites running on WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be easily done by installing some plugins in wp.
you can check this list on http://technomiz.com/2012/04/make-social-networking-sites-like-facebookorkut-etc/

Comment: An answer should be [more than a link to an external site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion). Please add some details, make sure your answer is still relevant if the linked site vanishes.